# questions about two different approaches of implementing paginated APIs

Tags: javascript, html, http

I wonder if for any request that can be potentially paginated, let's say it is an API for autosuggestions based on the given query and since the list of results that get back might be too long(when the query term is very vague). is it better to implement the API where it takes something like `nextToken` as part of its arguments and uses that to mark which batch of results the response should get back with, or instead of asking the client to specify that token, we use some sticky sessions over HTTP to achieve it? Which approach is better or when do we prefer one over the other?

One example of the first approach i.e. the one with `nextToken` would be

```js
sdk.getResults({queryTerm, nextToken, maxResults})
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you actually have to store "session states" for each client in the server side. That can become really complex to implement well and is certainly a resource consumer. Also breaks the stateless principle if you are workin in a REST architecture.

Comment: Isn't it easier to achieve the pagination with from: and to: parameters?